# Image is less Sharper

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

In my application I capture image from camera. At that time sharpness of my image is fantastic but with the following lines of code my image is moved to next view.

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromView:(UIView *)view {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

When I see the image in next view at that time it is less sharper than before.

I want to mention, on both screens height and width of image view is same.

then what should be the problem with sharpness of image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Line

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
```

instead of
 `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to offset the image by 0.5,0.5. Otherwise Quartz distributes each point amongst the 4 neighbors.

In Quartz 0.0 is the corner of a pixel, not its center.

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.5, 0.5);
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html

Comment: please explain in more words i had same problem before, Can you explain to do put code?